# python pandas: Generate (three) cells from one cell

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy

I have a simple dataframe consisting of some metadata in a few columns and then a column with a sentence in it. I would like to use textacy's SVO extractor to generate three new columns, one each for the subject, verb, and object. I am trying to do this in as pandas a way as possible:

```
metadata   sentence
1-0        Thank you so much, Chris.
1-1        And it's truly a great honor to be here. 
1-2        I have been blown away by this conference.
1-3        And I say that sincerely.
```

To which I tried this:

```py
def svo(text):
    svotriple = textacy.extract.triples.subject_verb_object_triples(nlp(text))
    for item in svotriple:
        df['subject'] = str(item[0][-1])
        df['verb']    = str(item[1][-1])
        df['object']  = str(item[2])

df.apply(svo(df['sentence'].values[0]))
```

I've tried to get just the sentence as a string out of the sentence column a couple of ways. Most of them returned the fact that I was actually getting a series. I want this to work row-by-row. My impulse was to go with a `for` loop, but I really want to try to do this the pandas way. (Not that my for loops were working terribly well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use `apply` is incorrect. You should create an empty DataFrame to store the SVO triples, you're directly updating the columns of the existing DataFrame in each iteration, which will overwrite the previous values.

Try this way

```
import pandas as pd
import textacy
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def svo(text):
    svotriples = textacy.extract.triples.subject_verb_object_triples(nlp(text))
    svo_list = []
    for item in svotriples:
        subject = str(item[0][-1])
        verb = str(item[1][-1])
        obj = str(item[2])
        svo_list.append([subject, verb, obj])
    return svo_list

data = {
    'sentence': [
        'Thank you so much, Chris.',
        "And it's truly a great honor to be here.",
        'I have been blown away by this conference.',
        'And I say that sincerely.'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[['subject', 'verb', 'object']] = df['sentence'].apply(svo).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)
```

Comment: This is working. I'd like to report complete success, but I'm getting `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` which I think is a matter, perhaps, of the SVO extractor reporting more than one SVO per sentence in some cases. This, however, lies outside the scope of the problem that you helped me solve! I'm going to have to study this one line very carefully to see how you did this so compactly.

Comment: Actually code above is not working when run on its own. Getting the ValueError even with data above?!

Comment: What do you mean by not working when run on its own please ?

Comment: When I kept getting the `ValueError` I wanted to explore if something in my data was throwing things off, so I copied and pasted the code above to see where things were wonky on my end. When I run the code as a cell in a separate (new) Jupyter notebook, I get the same error and it points as follows: `---> 28 df[['subject', 'verb', 'object']] = df['sentence'].apply(svo).apply(pd.Series)`. If you're not getting the error, then I wonder what's going on?

Comment: FWIW, this works but creates a single column with the list in it: `df['subject', 'verb', 'object'] = df['sentence'].apply(lambda x: svo(x))`

Comment: The error lay in the SVO function, which I have corrected. It should read:

Comment: ```python
def svo(text):
svo = list(textacy.extract.triples.subject_verb_object_triples(nlp(text)))
if not svo:
s = ''
v = ''
o = ''
else:
s = str(svo[0][0]).strip("[]")
v = str(svo[0][1][-1]).strip("[]")
o = str(svo[0][2]).strip("[]")
return s, v, o
```